# The reason why webGL produces so many minor page faults?

Tags: javascript, web, linux-kernel, webgl

I'm studying linux kernel, but I don't know much about web.
I saw some WebGL samples on browser(http://webglsamples.org/), and I tested it with perf, which is performance analysis tool of linux. 
What I saw was excessive number of minor page faults(about 10000~100000).
I traced these minor page faults and found that these faults occurs when accessing the allocated memory space for the first time.
This means WebGL applications repeatedly do following process.
1. Allocate memory space
2. Do computation
3. Free memory space
I'm trying to analyze the reason of these phenomenon.
 
But I know nothing about web environment, java script, and something like that...
Anyone can give some hints about this?
Why does WebGL application excessively repeat allocate/free memory space?

Comment: which browsers did you try? Was it all samples or only some?

Comment: @gman Ah sorry, I'm using Firefox. I didn't check all of the samples, but I tried several(10?) of them, and other I also tested on other WebGL based graphical websites. But there are no exceptions.

Comment: Can you try chrome ? It would help to know if it's a firefox thing or an OpenGL thing